# Setting `caption` parameters for `figures` and `tables` locally

Tags: graphics, captions

The answer to a question asked Jan 16 '13 at 4:54 by @manish continued into a discussion on how to set `caption` parameters locally. The suggestion that this would be done using `\captionsetup[figure]{..}` or `\captionsetup[table]{..}` inside the `figure` or `table` environment does not work for me either. How *can* this be done?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} %% Remove [demo] in your file
%\usepackage{caption}
%\captionsetup[table]{font=small,skip=0pt}     %% Adjust here
%or equivalently 
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}

\begin{document}

Some text...

\begin{figure}[htb]
\captionsetup[figure]{font=large,skip=10pt}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=1in,width=1in,angle=-90]{foo}
\caption{This is a figure.}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

More text...

\begin{figure}[htb]
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small,skip=0pt}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=1in,width=1in,angle=-90]{foo}
\caption{This is another figure.}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

Still more text...
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{This is a table.}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
    % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
    1 & 2 \\
    4 & 7 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

More text...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a link to the question before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the documentation of package `caption`, chapter 1, you have to use

```
\captionsetup{font=large,skip=10pt}
```

instead

```
\captionsetup[figure]{font=large,skip=10pt}
%            ^^^^^^^^
```

So with the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} %% Remove [demo] in your file
%\usepackage{caption}
%\captionsetup[table]{font=small,skip=0pt}     %% Adjust here
%or equivalently 
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}

\begin{document}

Some text...

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=1in,width=1in,angle=-90]{foo}
  \captionsetup{font=large,skip=10pt} % <===============================
  \caption{This is a figure.}
\end{figure}

More text...

\begin{figure}[htb]
\captionsetup{font=small,skip=-10pt} % <================================
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=1in,width=1in,angle=-90]{foo}
\caption{This is another figure.}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

Still more text...
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{This is a table.}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
    % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
    1 & 2 \\
    4 & 7 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

More text...

\end{document}
```

you get the result (I only used `-10pt` to make the second changing better visable):

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: … and as the statement is inside the specific environment, it works for `table` just the same.